# SQL Syntax error:：use parentheses() after FROM clause is wrong?

Tags: mysql, sql

Can you tell me why I can not use parentheses after FROM clause to treat it a whole table?

The two codes may can not run here.
The difference is the appearance of one more parentheses after FROM clause.

Right:

```
# right
SELECT t1.emp_no, t2.manager_no, t1.emp_salary, t2.manager_salary
FROM (SELECT de.emp_no emp_no, s1.salary emp_salary, de.dept_no
      FROM dept_emp de 
      JOIN salaries s1 
      ON de.emp_no = s1.emp_no
      WHERE de.to_date = '9999=01-01'
            AND s1.to_date = '9999=01-01'
            AND de.emp_no NOT IN (SELECT emp_no FROM dept_manager)
        ) t1
      JOIN (SELECT dm.emp_no manager_no, s2.salary manager_salary, dm.dept_no
            FROM dept_manager dm 
            JOIN salaries s2
            ON dm.emp_no = s2.emp_no 
            WHERE s2.to_date = '9999=01-01'
                  AND dm.to_date = '9999-01-01'
            ) t2
      ON t1.dept_no = t2.dept_no
WHERE t2.manager_salary < t1.emp_salary
```

Wrong:

```
# wrong
SELECT t.emp_no, t.manager_no, t.emp_salary, t.manager_salary
FROM ((SELECT de.emp_no emp_no, s1.salary emp_salary, de.dept_no
      FROM dept_emp de 
      JOIN salaries s1 
      ON de.emp_no = s1.emp_no
      WHERE de.to_date = '9999=01-01'
            AND s1.to_date = '9999=01-01'
            AND de.emp_no NOT IN (SELECT emp_no FROM dept_manager)
      ) t1 
      JOIN (SELECT dm.emp_no manager_no, s2.salary manager_salary, dm.dept_no
            FROM dept_manager dm 
            JOIN salaries s2
            ON dm.emp_no = s2.emp_no 
            WHERE s2.to_date = '9999=01-01'
                  AND dm.to_date = '9999-01-01'
            ) t2
      ON t1.dept_no = t2.dept_no
      ) t
WHERE t.manager_salary < t.emp_salary
```

The code may can not run here.
The difference is the apprence of one more parentheses after FROM clause.

Comment: Perhaps you need to do `(SELECT * FROM (SELECT de.emp_no ...`

Answer (score 1):

The part between the brackets in the `FROM` part must be a subquery. Your example has two subqueries and a join clause without the `select *` part. So it is not a subquery. Try adding `select *  from`  between the first two brackets.

Comment: Thanks so much, get it!

Brackets in SQL are just for subqueries instead of everything in a whole like things in math

Answer (score 0):

Seems your query have on extra brace

```
SELECT t.emp_no, t.manager_no, t.emp_salary, t.manager_salary
FROM (
     SELECT de.emp_no emp_no, s1.salary emp_salary, de.dept_no
     FROM dept_emp de 
     JOIN salaries s1 
     ON de.emp_no = s1.emp_no
     WHERE de.to_date = '9999=01-01'
        AND s1.to_date = '9999=01-01'
        AND de.emp_no NOT IN (SELECT emp_no FROM dept_manager)
     ) t1 
    JOIN 
    (
      SELECT dm.emp_no manager_no, s2.salary manager_salary, dm.dept_no
      FROM dept_manager dm 
      JOIN salaries s2
      ON dm.emp_no = s2.emp_no 
      WHERE s2.to_date = '9999=01-01'
               AND dm.to_date = '9999-01-01'
    ) t2
    ON t1.dept_no = t2.dept_no
  ) t
  WHERE t.manager_salary < t.emp_salary
```